# Dynamic property access of methods of an object with Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm getting up to speed on TypeScript from using flow, and I have a small puzzle...

```js
const methods: Array<keyof typeof console> = ["log", "error"];
beforeEach(() => {
  methods.forEach((m) => jest.spyOn(console, m).mockImplementation(() => {}));
});
```

I was hoping that would work, but I get this error:

```
error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(object: Console, method: FunctionPropertyNames<Required<Console>>): SpyInstance<any, unknown[]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'keyof Console' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionPropertyNames<Required<Console>>'.
      Type '"Console"' is not assignable to type 'FunctionPropertyNames<Required<Console>>'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(object: Console, method: ConstructorPropertyNames<Required<Console>>): SpyInstance<any, unknown[]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'keyof Console' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConstructorPropertyNames<Required<Console>>'.
      Type '"error"' is not assignable to type 'ConstructorPropertyNames<Required<Console>>'.

22     methods.forEach((m) => jest.spyOn(console, m).mockImplementation(() => {}));
```

So... what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give the `methods` correct type. The type should be all function property names extracted from `console`.

```
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never }[keyof T] & string;

const methods: FunctionPropertyNames<typeof console>[] = ['log', 'error'];

describe('69231740', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    methods.forEach((m) => jest.spyOn(console, m).mockImplementation());
  });
});
```

package versions:

```json
"@types/jest": "^26.0.18",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

Comment: That's amazing. Thanks so much, this gives me a lot of insight into TS and its utility types!